# Elm vs React: why no lifecycle functions in Elm?

Tags: reactjs, elm

I have built a couple of apps in Elm and now have built a couple in React.

In React I am offered functions like `shouldComponentUpdate` for when I might want to render a component less often.

It is only now that I am thinking: how come Elm does not have (or need) them?

Comment: Side note: With [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html), you typically don't need lifecycle methods anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the specific problem of re-rendering, out of the box Elm uses virtual DOM diffing: if its virtual DOM changed, the real DOM gets updated accordingly. This is much cheaper than working directly on the DOM.

Interestingly, Elm's behavior *when using `Html.lazy`* is the same as React's *when you define components as functions* (ie. not an object from a class inheriting from `Component` or `PureComponent`): since you do not rely on side effects (lifecycle functions being one appropriate example), given the same function inputs, your component will **always** produce the same output. This way, Elm or React only needs to re-render your component if its inputs somehow change. So, in this way, you don't have to care about whether your component needs to be re-rendered: Elm takes care of that.

So, what about these lifecycle methods? For instance:

- `shouldComponentUpdate`: as I mentioned above, when using `Html.lazy`, Elm checks whether your input changed: if it didn't, re-rendering is clearly not needed in a functional context. Otherwise, Elm will diff its virtual DOM. In both cases, though, Elm does not need to be told whether rendering is needed or not.
- `componentWillReceiveProps`: corresponds pretty much to your `update` function.
- `componentDidMount`: I don't think there's an equivalent to this one: either you component exists and gets rendered or it does not. This is very much like using a function as a component.

Comment: Elm doesn't automatically check whether the input has changed. It checks whether the output has changed, through diffing of the virtual dom. In order to run a view function only if the input has changed, if the rendering code itself is expensive, you have to use `Html.Lazy`. See https://guide.elm-lang.org/optimization/lazy.html

Comment: Thank you @glennsl, I mixed the lazy behavior with the vanilla one. I have updated my answer accordingly.